# How to properly remove SnapshotListeners?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I apologize if it's too easy of a question, but I'm a bit of a noob, so please bear with me.

I know the method for removing a snapshotListener `listener.remove()`, but I have multiple listeners that are all over the place and I need to remove the listeners upon the execution of `viewWIllDisappear`, so here is a sample of how I'm going about removing the listeners, but unfortunately this way of doing it doesn't actually remove the listeners. Any suggestions on how I should go about removing them?

Thank you in advanced!

```
        var authHandle : AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
        var addFeedback : ListenerRegistration?
        var deleteExerciseFeedback : ListenerRegistration?
        var deleteWsrFeedback : ListenerRegistration?
    
    //MARK: - viewWillDisappear()
        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            addFeedback?.remove()
            deleteExerciseFeedback?.remove()
            deleteWsrFeedback?.remove()
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(authHandle!)
            workoutsCollection.daysCollection.removeAll()
        }
    
    //MARK: - Load the Data
        func loadData(){
            addFeedback = self.rootWorkoutsCollection.order(by: "Timestamp", descending: false).addSnapshotListener({ (querySnapshot, err) in ...)}
    


   //MARK: - Delete TableViewCell
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                
                indexToRemove = indexPath
                
                
                let workoutRef = workoutsCollection.daysCollection[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row].workout
                
                //Deletes all WSR's when deleting Workouts...
                deleteWsrFeedback = rootWsrCollection.whereField("Workout", isEqualTo: workoutRef).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
                    
                    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {return}
    
                    for wsr in snapshot.documents{
                        print("Deleting WSR \(wsr.data())")
                        self.rootWsrCollection.document(wsr.documentID).delete()
                    }
                }
                
                //Deletes all Exercises when deleting Workouts...
                deleteExerciseFeedback = rootExerciseCollection.whereField("Workout", isEqualTo: workoutRef).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
                    
                    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {return}
                    
                    for exercise in snapshot.documents{
                        print("Deleting Exercise \(exercise.data())")
                        self.rootExerciseCollection.document(exercise.documentID).delete()
                    }
                    self.deleteExerciseFeedback?.remove()
                }
    
                //Deletes Workouts...
                let selectedKey = workoutsCollection.daysCollection[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row].key!
                rootWorkoutsCollection.document(selectedKey.documentID).delete()
                print("Workout Deleted: \(workoutsCollection.daysCollection[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row].workout)")
                workoutsCollection.daysCollection[indexPath.section].workout.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this will work in viewWillDisappear() as well but it works for me in deinit. First, check if the listener exists, if so remove it.

```
deinit {
    if deleteExerciseFeedback != nil {
        deleteExerciseFeedback.remove()
    }
}
```

Do the same with other listeners.